# Ignore variables from another shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcsh

I am on a linux workstation in a network, with an "old" distrib. Furthermore, login shell is enforced to CSH. I already asked to Admins if it would be possible to switch to another one (I would like to have bash), but it was a no-go...

Therefore, I am running bash from the command line, as an interactive non-login shell (actually I am using gnome and gnome-terminal with a profile that runs /bin/bash -i as the command). A lot, if not all of my scripts use bash so I run them from it invoking bash with a script. It is messy but it works.

I have .cshrc with environment variables, aliases and options for csh defined in a .login and a .cshrc files in my $HOME. I also have a .bashrc/.bash_profile(that redirects to .bashrc if this an interactive shell)/.bash_aliases with some other variables and some that are the same. When I run the bash shell, I inherit from the environments variables defined in my .login file. I would like to ignore everything that is set up in this one when I run bash.

I would like to know if there is an option to run bash, ignoring every other environment variables previously defined from my CSH login session when I run my BASH shell.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually unsetting variables you don't want to inherit, run bash using the `env` command:

```
env -i bash
```

The `-i` flag causes `bash` to ignore its inherited environment.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to run bash as non-interactive shell, inside CSH, with bash variables defined in .bash_profile right?

You could give a shoot:

```
./bash --login
source ./bash --login
```

but i can't test it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It did not do what I'd like too: a setenv $PLOUC "PLOUZ" defined in .cshrc is still giving me a PLOUZ when I do a echo $PLOUC after /bin/bash --login

Comment: so after `./bash --login` execute this `source .bash_profile`

Comment: Same result unfortunately...

Comment: Bash itself could inherit var from environment that was executed from, look for proper switch in `man bash`. If you just want to remove variables from the enviroment just `unset VARNAME1 VARNAME2`.

Comment: Well, I looked into the switch (actually, I tried them all, but with no luck). I thought of unsetting any one of them, but there are quite of them. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Print them all: `env | awk -F= '/^\w/ {print $1}' | xargs`, then remove those important one and unset.

Comment: okobaka I am going to accept @chepner's solution, which does better suit my needs. Thanks again for helping me!